# replace text in single line after specific occurence using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have searched for a solution to a problem on this site but have not found a way to do this task using regex (or perhaps something just shortened that uses less memory).
  I am attempting to parse a string where text after a specific pattern (& the pattern itself) is to be removed from the same line. The text prior to to the pattern and also any line not containing the search pattern should be unedited.

Here is a working example:

```
$text = 'This is a test to remove single lines.<br />
The line below has the open type bbcode (case insensitive) that is to be removed.<br />
The text on the same line that follows the bbcode should also be removed.<br />
this text should remain[test]this text should be removed on this line only!<br />
the other lines should remain.<br />
done.<br />';

$remove = '[test]';
$lines = preg_split('/\r?\n/', $text);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $check = substr($line, 0, stripos($line, $remove));
    $new[] = !empty($check) ? $check . '<br />' : $line;
}

$newText = implode($new);

echo $newText;
```

The above code works as expected but I would like to know how to do this using regex or perhaps something that uses a lot less code and memory. I have attempted to do this using regex from examples on this site + some tinkering but have not been able to get the result that is required. The solution should also use code that is compatible with PHP 5.5 syntax (no \e modifier). Using an array for the removal pattern will also be fitting as I may need to do a search for multiple patterns (although it is not shown in my example).

Thank you.

---

Thanks to frightangel for showing me the proper regex pattern.

Below is the necessary code to accomplish what was asked above:

```
$text = 'This is a test to remove single lines.<br />
The line below has the open type bbcode (case insensitive) that is to be removed.<br />
The text on the same line that follows the bbcode should also be removed.<br />
this text should remain[test]this text should be removed on this line only!<br />
the other lines should remain.<br />
[bbc]done.<br />
[another]this line should not be affected.<br />
it works!!<br />';

$removals = array('[test]', '[bbc]');
$remove = str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('~\[', '\].*?(?=\<br\s\/\>|\\n|\\r)~mi'), $removals);  
$text = preg_replace($remove, '', $text);

echo $text;
```

The text that it searches for actually comes from a mysql query that feeds an array so I changed what is shown above to use what will more or less be used ($removals being that array).

The only problem left for me is that if text was prior to the removal then it would be better to leave the final line break from that line instead of omitting it. It should only be omitted if all text from a single line is removed.

Comment: What your expected output from the above?

Comment: Nice change you did. That is the thing, always improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$text = 'This is a test to remove single lines.<br />
The line below has the open type bbcode (case insensitive) that is to be removed.<br />
The text on the same line that follows the bbcode should also be removed.
this text should remain[test]this text should be removed on this line only!<br />
the other lines should remain.<br />
done.<br />';

$remove = 'test';

$text = preg_replace("/\[$remove\].*(?=\<br\s\/\>)/m", '', $text);
$text = preg_replace("/^(\<br\s\/\>)|(\\n)|(\\r)$/m","",$text);

echo $text;
```

Here's regex explanation: http://regex101.com/r/nW1bG8

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Btw the search removal pattern is [test] (with the square brackets) since I do not want it to edit any line with just the word test in it. Anyhow, this does not work as requested.

Comment: This matches the brackets also. I had to remove from $remove cause [] are specials in regex, so you need to escape them. I just run it and it was just fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89f90f833002e73e0223f2aa716795c0b818f38b

Comment: Ok I see what you did there. Will this also work with all possible types of line breaks? ie. \r\n

Comment: to match also \n and \r, use this regex:

    `'/\[$remove\].*(?=(?=\<br\s\/\>)|(?=\\n)|(?=\\r))/m'`

Comment: Better yet, `'~\[test\].*(?=<br\s*/>|\R)~'`

Comment: fnightangel, thanks - almost perfect. The only thing is that on the line it removed the text from the line break (at the end only) should remain. currently it omits that line break and what should be the next line starts on the same one as 'this text should remain'.

Comment: perhaps I should be more specific with my statement. If there is other text prior to the search pattern on the same line then the ending line break should remain (either <br /> \r or \n). If there is no other text on the line that is edited except what comes after the search pattern then the line break should be removed.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the new line I just add in solution will replace any `<br />`, `\n` or `\r` "alone" in the line

Comment: The second regex you posted does not seem to work as intended whereas when only omitted text was on an edited line it still showed a line break. Also even if it did work, it would then remove line breaks from lines that did not originally get edited from the 1st regex command. I emended my first post with the solution you provided thus far. It also states the pending dilemma I have regarding line breaks. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I think to get it to work I need two removal patterns. One that works when there is text prior to the removal and the other that works when it is the entire line being removed. When there was text the replacement is a <br /> and when the entire line is removed the replacement is '' ...

Comment: The regex condition you posted did not work as expected when I tested this to filter posts as intended (although it did whilst testing s simple string). However I was able to get it working by changing the condition a bit which is now reflected in my first post. Thanks again for putting me on the right track.

Comment: This worked for me on a local installation but not live on my forum. Does anyone have any other ideas? I need it to remove the ie. [test] bbc closed tag along with all text on the same line directly after the tag nut just until a new line. A new line can be \n \r or xhtml <br />

Answer (score 0):

try this, and tell me if thats what you want
if not, tell me, i probably didnt understand your question

```
 preg_replace("/\[\S+\].+<[^>]+\s?\/>|<[^>]+\s?\/>/m","",$text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Sinius_Black but that pattern does not work properly. Please run the example I gave to get an idea of what has been requested. What I am asking is to do that exact task/result but perhaps using one line of regex code.

Comment: i tried the code and it returned "This is a test to remove single lines. The line below has the open type bbcode (case insensitive) that is to be removed. The text on the same line that follows the bbcode should also be removed. okok the other lines should remain. done." exactly what you script returned

Comment: Your example removed all line breaks and any line that contained other bb code (<- square brackets around text). This is not what was requested as the search pattern needs to be more specific in that regard.